# Lexicographic Rank of First $n$ Natural Numbers Permutation

Tags: number-theory, permutations

Given a permutation $\pi$ of the first $n$ natural numbers $[1,2,...,n]$. I need to find the lexicographic rank of this permutation, that is the $1$-based index of this permutation when all $n!$ permutations are written in lexicographical order. Is there a fast way to find this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine $n=5$ and $\pi=[3,4,1,5,2]$. Given that $[1,2,3,4,5]$ is at position $1$ and $[5,4,3,2,1]$ is at position $120$, we wish to find the position of $\pi$.

We can do this by reading the digits of $\pi$ from left to right, and finding their **relative** value in the associated set of remaining digits.

The first one is easy. In this case we have $3$. This means that the permutation is in the $3^{rd}$ $5-tile$, i.e. $pos(\pi)\in[49,72]$.

The remaining digits are $4,1,5,2$. The next digit is $4$ and this is ordered $3^{rd}$ from the set. This means that in our range of $24$, it lies in the $3^{rd}$ quarter, so now we have $pos(\pi)\in[62,67]$.

Next we have $1$ which is ordered first in $1,5,2$, and therefore $pos(\pi)\in[62,63]$.

$5$ is next, telling us that $pos(\pi)=63$.